# sending xml response from cakephp

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I want to send an xml response from my a controller action of cakephp. I have been trying to follow the official guide: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

But i keep getting this error:

```
Missing View

Error: The view for ServicesController::index() was not found.
```

this is what my services controller looks like:

```
<?php
class ServicesController extends AppController {

    var $uses = array();
    var $components = array('Auth','Session','RequestHandler');

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index');
    }

    function index(){
        $output = array(
            "status" => "OK",
            "message" => "You are good"
        );

        $this->set('output', $output );
        $this->set('_serialize', array("output"));
   }
}
?>
```

I have also added the following line to my `routes.php`

```
Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xml');
```

what could be the thing that im doing wrong??

Comment: I originally answered that you just need to create a view file, but it appears I was wrong - according to the book, at least, you shouldn't need one.

Comment: exactly! there is this one more link that i found which also says the same: http://yihangho.com/cakephp-json-and-xml-response-explained/

Comment: Did you forget to add .xml extension to your url (http://example.com/services/index.xml)?

Comment: @AndrewBashtannik You beat me to it. This is most likely the answer here. Using parseExtensions only makes sense if you actually use extensions.

Comment: yes, im adding the extension to url. Tried both json and xml. Even tried testing with a CURL

Comment: Most probable cause is that your request is simply not recognized as xml. Try checking in the action, before executing any code, whether the index.xml is using "xml code". Try with [isXml](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent::isXml) and check the extension under `params` (I believe it's still there). And see what extensions are really recognized with [Router::extensions()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/source-class-Router.html#1099-1120) (never used it but it looks simple enough). Update the question with the debug info.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to convert your array to XML, echo the output and exit the function:

```
function index(){
    $output = array(
        "root" => array( // It needs one top element (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html#transforming-an-array-into-a-string-of-xml)
            "status" => "OK",
            "message" => "You are good"
        )
    );

    $xmlObject = Xml::fromArray($output);
    echo $xmlObject->asXML();
    exit;
}
```